# How to get the only the total files size from folders in windows commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

How to get the only the total files size from folders dir in windows commandline
[self answered]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Googling shows many examples. What have you tried? Do you get any error?

Comment: Ty, I have a self answer, but couldn't use the check box and do it concurrently because I have no reputation

Comment: … and now you have some ;) You might still have to wait a while before it will let you mark the answer as accepted. Welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on Powershell:

```
gci Downloads | measure Length -s
```

To see the result in MB:

```
(gci Downloads | measure Length -s).Sum /1MB
```

More details on the available options, how to include the subdirectories etc. available here:

https://4sysops.com/archives/measure-object-computing-the-size-of-folders-and-files-in-powershell/

Comment: I've been too long out of the community... thanks @Mokubai for reminding me of the bare basics :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have found elsewhere that

```
dir /a/s
```

lists all files and folders

But to tidy this up we can use findstr, the tail of the dir command is like

```
Total files listed:
    nn File(s) n,nnn,nnn  bytes
    mm Dir(s)  p,pppp,ppp  bytes free
```

So

```
dir /a/s | findstr "Dir(s)"
```

shows the last line, which is the free bytes on the disk

Another search example

```
dir /a/s | findstr "Dir.File(s)"
```

*findstr looks for each string separated by a space*

So it also shows the file space used in each sub folder